# Discordpy buttons avoid button spam

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there any simplistic way to avoid people from spamming a button, I have a ticket bot with a simple discord button and embed, but people can spam the button 5-10 times and create numerous tickets. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own cooldown for buttons, here is an example taken from the discord.py discord server:

```py
class ButtonOnCooldown(commands.CommandError):
  def __init__(self, retry_after: float):
    self.retry_after = retry_after

# you can also use a lambda if it's simple enough
# this function works similarly to the `key` in functions `sorted` and `list.sort`
def key(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  return interaction.user

class View(discord.ui.View):
  def __init__(self, *, timeout: float = 180.0):
    super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
    self.value = 0
    # create a CooldownMapping with a rate of 1 token per 3 seconds using our key function
    self.cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1.0, 3.0, key)

  async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    retry_after = self.cd.update_rate_limit(interaction)
    if retry_after:
      # rate limited
      # we could raise `commands.CommandOnCooldown` instead, but we only need the `retry_after` value
      raise ButtonOnCooldown(retry_after)

    # not rate limited
    return True

  async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error: Exception, item: discord.ui.Item):
    if isinstance(error, ButtonOnCooldown):
      seconds = int(error.retry_after)
      unit = 'second' if seconds == 1 else 'seconds'
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"You're on cooldown for {seconds} {unit}!", ephemeral=True)
    else:
      # call the original on_error, which prints the traceback to stderr
      await super().on_error(interaction, error, item)

  @discord.ui.button(label='Count', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  async def count(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    self.value += 1
    await interaction.response.send_message(self.value, ephemeral=True)

# send the view
await ctx.send('Start counting!', view=View())
```